# Ignore .classpath file while sync CVS in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I know that you can ignore the file (preference-team-ignore resources) type while committing to CVS from eclipse however how can I ignore the file type being synchronized with CVS. I have got 40 project in workspeace and every time I sync with CVS, it list all the .classpath files from all the project however I would like to ignore this file to make CVS sync view better.

any help will be appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can add the .classpath file to the .cvsignore file.  In Eclipse, you should be able to right click on the .classpath file and go to Team -> Add to .cvsignore.  [Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_function_of_the_.cvsignore_file?) are some additional details.

Comment: Hi Mike, with this option you can ignore a particular file type during CVS check-in while I want to ignore particular file type during the sync process itself. I dont have answer for this yet and still looking to get :-(